# Is there a way to determine unused files and includes with Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

Over time, I've collected quite some assets (i.e., images, etc.) and `_includes` in my Jekyll website that I don't use anymore.

Is there an easy way to locate:

1. `_includes` that aren't in use anymore
2. Assets that aren't being used (or referenced in the HTML) anymore

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no in-built method to do that. If there's a plugin for that, I don't know. Anyways, it sounds like it wouldn't be very complicated to do, using some html parser to generate a map of the site and a filesystem library, to check which files don't appear in the map.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to use the `--profile` option with your build command. It will give you a list of includes you *are* using. This will do nothing for assets, but it's a start.